# Base64 is breaking lines when encoding in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I am encoding an image to `Base64` using the following code snippet in delphi.

```
procedure TWM.WMactArquivosAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
  Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ImagePath: string;
  JsonObject: TJSONObject;
  inStream, outStream: TStream;
  StrList: TStringList;
begin
  inStream := TFileStream.Create(ImagePath, fmOpenRead);
  try
    outStream := TFileStream.Create('final_file', fmCreate);
    JsonObject := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(inStream, outStream);
      outStream.Position := 0;
      StrList := TStringList.Create;
      StrList.LoadFromStream(outStream);

      JsonObject.AddPair('file', StrList.Text);
    finally
      Response.Content := JsonObject.ToString;
      outStream.Free;
      JsonObject.DisposeOf;
    end;
  finally
    inStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It works fine, the file is converted to `Base64` and added to the `JsonObject`.

The problem is that when retrieving this `JsonObject` from the webserver I get a bad json formatted because **there are line breaks** in the base64 string.

[image: bad json formatted]

You can see that the red one is the string. After the first line break the json is disturbed and it shows in blue, meaning that there is an error in the json response.

**The problem**

So, the problem is that when encoding to `Base64` it is adding line breaks to the string and this is not supported in `Json`.

**My Guess**

I have a guess, which indeed worked but I am not sure this is the best solution.

I looped through all the `Strings` in the `TStringList` and added the data into a `TStringBuilder`. After all, I added the `TStringBuilder` to the `Json`. Look at my code.

```
...
var
  ...
  StrBuilder: TStringBuilder;
begin
  ...
    try
      ...
      StrList.LoadFromStream(outStream);

      // New
      StrBuilder := TStringBuilder.Create;
      for I := 0 to StrList.Count - 1 do
        StrBuilder.Append(StrList.Strings[I]);

      JsonObject.AddPair('file', StrBuilder.ToString);
    finally
      Response.Content := JsonObject.ToString;
      ...
    end;
  ...
end;
```

[image: well json formatted]

As you can see the JSON is fine now.

**The question**

1. Looping through all the items seems a bad solution for me, will it work fine? (It is getting the response in 344ms on localhost)
2. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the convenience instance `TNetEncoding.Base64` create your own instance and specify the `CharsPerLine` parameter in `Create` with 0.

```
  encoding := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
  try
    encosing.Encode(inStream, outStream);
  finally
    encoding.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Quite a few dupes of this question out there.....